# How do I flag a flag?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

I had flagged a comment as `obsolete`, but I was wrong!

Then I thought *It does not matter... it will be declined.*, but **it was not**!

So how can I bring this error to the attention of the moderators?

Comment: It was a comment; comments don't really count.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is not a good reason to forget it.

Comment: Moderators may disagree. You can try and flag the post on which the comment was posted and ask it to be un-deleted, but I'm not sure if they'll actually do this.

Comment: That comment should still be deleted anyways, as too chatty. The conversation: "Did you come up with this idea?" - "no, just harvested her from Google and confirmed it worked. Enjoy!" - Not useful to anything. So I deleted the comment that started that conversation too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just a comment flag. It has absolutely no effect on your flagging abilities whatsoever.

Mistakes happen. Mistakes related to comment flags are completely inconsequential and you have better things to worry about.

Furthermore, comments are ephemeral and fragile by design. We generally never bother undeleting comments by request, even though we have the ability to do so. Again, we have better things to worry about.

Comment: So should I avoid flagging _Thank you!_ comments as `too chatty`?

Comment: @Joiner Please read Shog's comment flaggers' manual: [A guide to moderating comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237980/266094)

Comment: @Unihedron I know, I was referring to _We have better things to worry about._.

Comment: "We have better things to worry about.." refers to your query on whether to flag for comments to be undeleted. Whether comments are flag-worthy is a question of which its answer is within the manual. Not sure where you're getting at @Joiner

Comment: @Unihedron Have `too chatty` comments to be removed or it does not matter because they have better things to worry about?